# How can I make this [3,3+3] to this [33,+,3] array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I need help! I'm stuck in javascript. I want to make a calculator.
And for this I need a javascript code that makes this array (e.g.:array1=[3,3,+,3]) into one (array2=[33,+,3]).
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), how to [access properties](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), and how to create [objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) or [arrays](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#array_literal_notation), and use the static and instance methods of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+in+array+of+digits+and+operators%2C+merge+consecutive+digits+into+numbers) of [Filter numbers from an array calculator](/a/56520515/4642212). However, `[ 33, "+", 3 ]` is not likely to be a very useful representation.